# PyGTK Window Resizing errors on OS X

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I'm still really new to PyGTK, but I would like to use it none the less.

I just got my basic window program setup when I got this error:

> Dec 31 21:09:20 Eamonns-MacBook-Pro.local Python[33609] : clip:
>   empty path.
>   /Users/Eamonn/Programming/Python/GUI/PyGTK/Tutorials/main.py:17:
>   GtkWarning: gdk_window_get_events: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)'
>   failed   gtk.main()
>   /Users/Eamonn/Programming/Python/GUI/PyGTK/Tutorials/main.py:17:
>   Warning: g_object_ref: assertion`G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
>   gtk.main()
>   /Users/Eamonn/Programming/Python/GUI/PyGTK/Tutorials/main.py:17:
>   GtkWarning: gdk_window_get_effective_toplevel: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed   gtk.main() [Finished in 13.0s with
>   exit code -11] [shell_cmd: python -u
>   "/Users/Eamonn/Programming/Python/GUI/PyGTK/Tutorials/main.py"] [dir:
>   /Users/Eamonn/Programming/Python/GUI/PyGTK/Tutorials] [path:
>   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Here is my code for the window:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk
import pygtk

pygtk.require('2.0')


class HelloWorld(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

    self.window.show()

def main(self):
    gtk.main()

hw = HelloWorld()
hw.main()
```

(sorry if  the indenting is weird, StackExchange kinda messed up the indenting when I formatted the code to use the code markdown)

I can easily reproduce this error by dragging the window rightwards from the right side, but not from the right corners. All the other sides resize fine when I drag them, and the green resize button works fine, too.

I'm running on a mid-2012 MacBook Pro with a 240GB SSD and 16GB RAM, upgraded myself. Before that it was just a standard mid-2012 MacBook Pro base model.

Any more information can be provided if necessary.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you aware that pyGTK is for GTK 2 only ? Checking the availability of GTK 3 on OS X and moving to pyGObject (python bindings for GTK 3) might be a wiser choice.

Comment: pygtk.require('2.0') -- does this not make sure I'm using GTK 2?

Comment: Sure it does. But learning how to use an outdated API isn't necessarily a good thing. Learning how to use the current version will save you the migration later.

Comment: So pyGObject is basically the new PyGTK? I thought it was just a dependency it required and was based on it or something xD I didn't think it was newer. Maybe this'll fix my problem. Thanks :-)

Comment: @liberforce: Does it mean that PyGTK is not supported on Mac OSX any more? I hit the same issue and I cannot upgrade to PyGObject right now - and honestly I even don't want.

Comment: No idea. I'm a GTK user on Linux, don't know the state on OS X, but last pyGTK release is from 2011, so don't expect much activity. Try asking directly on the pyGTK mailing list: http://www.pygtk.org/feedback.html